# Comparing array against an array group

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to compare one array, against another array.

```
$dropship_array = array();
$dropship_query = tep_db_query("select id, email from drop_shippers");
  while ($dropship = tep_db_fetch_array($dropship_query)) {
    $dropship_array[] = array('id' => $dropship['id'],
                            'email' => $dropship['email']);
  }
```

Now, $dropship_array[] contains:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
  [id] => 0
  [email] => none 
 ) 

 [1] => Array ( 
  [id] => 2 
  [email] => dropshipper1@gmail.com 
 ) 

 [2] => Array ( 
  [id] => 5 
  [email] => dropshipper2@gmail.com 
 )

 [2] => Array ( 
  [id] => 10 
  [email] => dropshipper3@gmail.com 
 ) 
)
```

Now, I need to compare the array above (dropship_array['id']) against the array bellow (products_array['dsid']). The products_array[] array has been split so that each individual array is grouped together according to each ones [dsid]. So every time a match is found between a group of products and the drop ship id, a function needs to be performed.

```
$products_array = array();
$products_query = tep_db_query("select products_id, products_name, drop_ship_id from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " where orders_id = '" . (int)$orders['orders_id'] . "' order by products_name");
while ($products = tep_db_fetch_array($products_query)) {
  $products_array[] = array('id' => $products['products_id'],
                            'text' => $products['products_name'],
            'dsid' => $products['drop_ship_id']);
}

Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 793 
        [text] => Gun Dog Training Book 
        [dsid] => 8 
      ) 
   ) 

   [1] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
       [id] => 789 
       [text] => Top Dog II Training DVD Video 
       [dsid] => 5 
      ) 

      [1] => Array ( 
       [id] => 237 
       [text] => Tri-Tronics Retriever Training Book 
       [dsid] => 5 
      ) 
   ) 
)
```

Would this require a foreach function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$one = array(
            '0' => array(
                'id' => '0',
                'email' => 'none'
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'email' => 'none'
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'email' => 'none'
            ),
            '3' => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'email' => 'none'
            )
        );

        $two = array(
            '0' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'id' => '793',
                    'text' => 'derp',
                    'dsid' => '8'
                )
            ),
            '1' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'id' => '793',
                    'text' => 'derp',
                    'dsid' => '8'
                ),
                '1' => array(
                    'id' => '793',
                    'text' => 'derp',
                    'dsid' => '3'
                )
            ),
        );

        foreach($one as $item) {
            foreach($two as $compare) {
                if(is_array($compare)) {
                    foreach($compare as $multicompare) {
                        if($multicompare['dsid'] == $item['id']) {
                            // Perform function
                        }
                    }
                  } 
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Breaking it down:

- First `foreach()` loops through the very first array from your drop_shippers table.
- Second `foreach()` loops through your next array and checks if the item is an array, if so it compares the `dsid` with the `id` from the first array.